# Stopwatch Timer doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer, stopwatch

I am a beginning JavaScript "coder" (PHP/C# knowledge) and I have to make a stopwatch.

Now I have a problem; each time the start button the timer will go faster and the stop(pause) button will stop working. I can't seem to find a proper way to fix it!

```js
var display = document.getElementById("timer"),
    start = document.getElementsByClassName("start"),
    stop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop"),
    seconds = 0,
    minutes = 0,
    hours = 0,
    time;



start[0].addEventListener('click', startTimer);
stop[0].addEventListener('click', stopTimer);



function startTimer() {
    timer();
    time = setInterval( timer, 1000);

}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(time);
}


function timer(){
    display.innerHTML = ExtraZero(hours)+":"+ExtraZero(minutes)+":"+ExtraZero(seconds);

    seconds++;

    if (seconds >= 60){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if (minutes >= 60){
            minutes = 0;
            hours ++;
        }
    }
}



function ExtraZero(i) {
    if (i < 10)
    {
        i = "0" + i
    }
    return i
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="stopwatch">

    <div class="timer">
        <p id="timer">00:00:00</p>
    </div>

    <div class="start">
        <button>START</button>
    </div>

    <div class="stop">
        <button>STOP</button>
    </div>

</div>




<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arent checking whether the timer is currently active when clicking start- and only running if not. As such, each time you click, the function is being run regardless...so you see it speeding up.

To remedy, set `time` to null initiaally and when stopping, then check this state when starting the timer.

```js
var display = document.getElementById("timer"),
  start = document.getElementsByClassName("start"),
  stop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop"),
  seconds = 0,
  minutes = 0,
  hours = 0,
  time = null; /* <--- set to null initially, not necessarily needed but makes things clear */



start[0].addEventListener('click', startTimer);
stop[0].addEventListener('click', stopTimer);



function startTimer() {
  if (time === null) { /* <--- only run the start function if the timer is not currently set */
    timer();
    time = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  }

}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(time);
  time = null; /* <-- exclicitely clean the timer variable */
}


function timer() {
  display.innerHTML = ExtraZero(hours) + ":" + ExtraZero(minutes) + ":" + ExtraZero(seconds);

  seconds++;

  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }
}



function ExtraZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }
  return i
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="stopwatch">

    <div class="timer">
      <p id="timer">00:00:00</p>
    </div>

    <div class="start">
      <button>START</button>
    </div>

    <div class="stop">
      <button>STOP</button>
    </div>

  </div>




  <script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you have more than one interval running if you start multiple times.
So update will be faster.

try the following:

```
var display = document.getElementById("timer"),
start = document.getElementsByClassName("start"),
stop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop"),
seconds = 0,
minutes = 0,
hours = 0,
time;
run = false;


start[0].addEventListener('click', startTimer);
stop[0].addEventListener('click', stopTimer);



function startTimer() {

if (!run){
    timer();
    run = true;
    time = setInterval( timer, 1000);
}else{
    alert("Timer already running");
}
}

function stopTimer() {
clearInterval(time);
run = false;
}


function timer(){
display.innerHTML = ExtraZero(hours)+":"+ExtraZero(minutes)+":"+ExtraZero(seconds);

seconds++;

if (seconds >= 60){
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;

    if (minutes >= 60){
        minutes = 0;
        hours ++;
    }
}
}



function ExtraZero(i) {
if (i < 10)
{
    i = "0" + i
}
return i
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

[timerWorking](http://jsfiddle.net/ba2zbq6v/)

I added a variable, so the script knows the timer is running and not starting it again.
On stop, the variable will be set to false and everything is back to normal. Start button will be working again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean named counting, add that to your variables

```
counting = false,
```

Next you can check on `function startTimer` if it is true with an if function
so you'll get

```
function startTimer() {
    if (counting == false){
        counting = true
        timer();
        time = setInterval( timer, 1000);
    }
}
```

And you can do the same for the `function stopTimer` but then if its true:

```
function stopTimer() {
    if (counting == true){
        counting = true;
        clearInterval(time);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work at all in my browser so I have simplified it by using `onClick()` to give button funtionality, and used `-1` as the timer off flag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stopwatch</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0;
var time = -1;

function ExtraZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function timer() {
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "" + ExtraZero(hours) + ":" + ExtraZero(minutes) + ":" + ExtraZero(seconds);
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }
}

function startTimer() {
  if (time == -1) {
    timer();
    time = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  }
}

function stopTimer() {
  if (time != -1) {
    clearInterval(time);
    time = -1;
  }
}

function resetTimer() {
  stopTimer();
  hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="stopwatch">
    <div class="timer"><p id="timer">00:00:00</p></div>
    <div class="start"><button onClick='startTimer()'>START</button></div>
    <div class="stop"><button onClick='stopTimer()'>STOP</button></div>
    <div class="reset"><button onClick='resetTimer()'>RESET</button></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We're not allowed to use the onClick function with this assignment! Thanks anyways :)